# Sorting the Excel Sheet by Partial Values in the Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have some columns in an Excel sheet and each row has different data. Around 3,000 rows are there in the Excel. As shown below:

```
SeNo    Object  contents
2   Zclss   5mport sy-mandt = '080'
5   Zclss   abcd sy-mandt = '070'
3   zinvice cVb sy-mandt = '060'
6   Zclss   exportsy-mandt = '050'
7   Zclss   import sy-mandt = '060'
1   zmed    import sy-mandt = '070'
4   zgood   jmport sy-mandt = '050'
```

Each row has one data which contains some number. Now My requireMt is arrange the data in Excel sheet according the number along with data. The Value in the Column Assume if there `070` in column “C” comes 70 rows.  I want then all rows containing number `070` in one sheet or the show in order

```
1   zmed    import sy-mandt = '070'
5   Zclss   abcd sy-mandt = '070'
4   zgood   jmport sy-mandt = '050'
6   Zclss   exportsy-mandt = '050'
7   Zclss   import sy-mandt = '060'
3   zinvice cVb sy-mandt = '060'
2   Zclss   5mport sy-mandt = '080'
```

They need not be same order benter code hereut I want all `070` one side and 50 so on….

*How do I solve this issue?*

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is about a job.

1) First extract the string parts which contains three digit numbers (`070` etc.) from the values in `C` column to another empty (or a new) column.

2) Then first order by the `A` column then order again by the new column. (Don't forget the select header cells -not the entire column- of each column before order if you do this on the sheet.)

You will see that the data will be grouped by the three digit numbers and ordered by the `Sello` in each group.

This operation can be done by but does not need vba.